# onepage scroller apple mouse wheel doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am using this [jQuery One Page scroll](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html#2)

Now I got it to work with my rails app, but what I noticed later is that I want it to scroll to the next page when I scroll with my mouse wheel one step.

am I doing something wrong here ? Since the [demo](http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html#2) doesn't work when I scroll with my mouse wheel. I did read the documentation and by default the mouse wheel option is on, but it still wont work.

here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/84bcdnba/)

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".main").onepage_scroll({
      sectionContainer: "section", 
      easing: "ease",
      animationTime: 1000,
      pagination: true,
      updateURL: false
    });

  });


</script>


<div class="main">
  <section class="n1 section" >
    <p class="n1_text_top">first</p>
    <p class="n1_text_sub">second</p>
  </section>
  <section class="n1 section" >
    <p class="n1_text_top"></p>
    <p class="n1_text_sub"></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Works for me using Chrome 41.0.2272.101. It takes several clicks of my mouse wheel to scroll, but other than that it works fine, what are you viewing it on?

Comment: I am using Chrome Version 42.0.2311.90 m, no ide why it does not work

Comment: Okej, It works on all other browsers like Vivalid, IE FF, but not chrome 42.0.2311. This is really strange

Comment: Updated to 42.0.2311.90, the demo page is still working as before. Try disabling any extensions you have running.

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead ?